# how to return anonymos data type in select with sqllite.net?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

i have a sqllite database that use it in xamarin android.
i want to select 2column of 2table that joined it.
how return query result without create a model class?

```
var query = select tbl1.Key,tbl2.value from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on tbl1.id==tbl2.id
```

and code:

```
var con= new SQLiteConnection();
....
Dictionary<string,string> result=con.Query<????>(query);
```

how do this **without** "create model class and then convert list to dictionary"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, the column name need to fit a property otherwise you will receive a "`value cannot be null`" error.